# Non zero exit status while installing R package TM

Tags: r, tm

I am new to R and am currently getting the following error while installing the package "tm". Any help in deciphering would be appreciated.

```
> install.packages("tm")
Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL '/src/contrib/tm_0.7-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 508463 bytes (496 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 496 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tm’ ...
** package ‘tm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -m64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: That's the entire error message? You didn't cut anything out? Normally there's at least a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: Does `Sys.which("g++")` return a path?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but when I install "tm", the dependencies are "NLP" and "slam".  Maybe check if you can install both of them first to see if the problem is there instead, then if that works, try to install "tm" again.